# Rails: How do I reference the model of the page I'm currently on?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

here's what I'm trying to do.  I am creating a classroom management system.  On the "assignments" page, I want users to create a submission from the submissions model.  I'm doing this by rendering a partial of a form on that page.  I have that part done.  The problem is when I'm submitting the submission.  I want it to pull the submission.assignment_id from the page that I'm currently on which is websites/assignments/{assignment_id}.  What's the best way to do this?

Here's what I tried to do to pull the assignment_id, but it didn't work:

```
class SubmissionsController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @submission = Submission.new
    end
    def create
        @assignment = Assignment.find(params[:id])
        @submission = Submission.new
        @submission.user_id = current_user.id
        @submission.assignment_id = @assignment.id
        if @submission.save
            flash[:success] = "The submission was successfully submitted."
            redirect_to units_path
        else 
            flash[:success] = "Submission was not submitted correctly, please try again."
            redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)

        end
    end

    def show
        @show = Submission.find(params[:id])
    end

end
```

Here's the submissions partial

```
<%= form_with model: @submission do |form| %>
    <div class="field">
        <%= form.label :content %>
        <%= form.rich_text_area :content %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="submitbutton">
        <div align = "center">
            <%= form.submit  class: "btn waves-effect waves-light" %>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Let me know if I need to provide any more detail.

Comment: The error I'm getting is: "ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Assignment without an ID):"  It also isn't allowing me to submit it, however I'm not sure if thats the same problem or because of a different one.

Comment: If submissions belong to assignments you could be handling this via routes, the form would post to the assignment/id/submissions/new action. Look into resourceful routing.

Comment: Right, didn;t notice this is the Submissions controller, you probably can set this in the form using a hidden field and setting it's value to the `params[:id]` value which will be for the assignment, not submission, can you share the form code you are using?

Comment: Rockwell, am I doing it wrong when I do "@assignment = Assignment.find(params[:id])"  as that's what I'm going for.  I will edit post with the show page form.

Comment: I tried adding it to the form with: <%@submission.assignment_id = Assignment.find(params[:id])%> and got a similar error

Comment: you don't need to do that, you already have the assignment_id because of the page you are on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are on the assignments page you can grab the id there and just pass it as part of the form

```
<%= form_with model: @submission do |form| %>

  <%= form.text_field :assignment_id, value: @assignment.id, class: 'hidden' %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :content %>
    <%= form.rich_text_area :content %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" id="submitbutton">
    <div align = "center">
        <%= form.submit  class: "btn waves-effect waves-light" %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

If the field shows, then you have to add a css rule to make the `hidden` class do `display:none;` . This would go in your site-wide stylesheet.

```
.hidden {display:none;}
```

You do not have access to the `params[:id]` of the page in the SubmssionsController which is why you are getting that error.  Remove the line trying to find that.

```
def create
    @submission = Submission.new
    @submission.user_id = current_user.id

    if @submission.save
        flash[:success] = "The submission was successfully submitted."
        redirect_to units_path
    else 
        flash[:success] = "Submission was not submitted correctly, please try again."
        redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)

    end
end
```

And, since I cannot see it, make sure `assignment_id` is in the list of permitted parameters for a submission.